# Can I print a rolled up schedule?

Tags: printing, microsoft-project, microsoft-project-2013

I currently have a schedule with about 100 total tasks. Of these, there are only about 15 summary tasks. I am trying to do a presentation and only need the summary tasks at the moment.

I have rolled up the summaries, but when I go to print it is still showing all 100 tasks. Does Project have a way to print the schedule as I am viewing it?

Comment: I believe a top level task report is what you need: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-and-print-a-basic-report-f566bfd5-f9e5-4b69-9963-822c8a49b559

Comment: @Lister That description appears to be what I need, is that option still available in Project 2013?

Comment: Acording to JulieS, no. I would try their answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How have you "rolled up" the summaries?  On the **View Tab**, click **Outline** and choose **Level 1**.  That should hide all of the subtasks underneath the summary.  Then check print preview.

The report Lister notes is no longer available in Project 2013.